# do not send report if there is no data in the table for specified report date

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

i have created a SSRS report and also created a subscription to attach the report in the email . This works perfectly fine.

I have to pass the Report date parameter in the report to capture any data. For that specific day, if there are records then send report else do not send report.

I have tried Data driven subscription and given below query in edit dataset and pass this as TO Email ID field.

```
select 'aaa.bbb@xxx.com' EmailID
where 1<=(select count(1) records from dbo.table)
```

and in parameter field, i am passing the date parameter .

i followed this video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TOdKNWVes5g

If there are any rows for that specified date  then it sends to above email ID else it shouldn't send as no data is retrieved. 
How ever, email is sent in both the cases with the report. if there is data, report has data else report is empty.

I do not want to send the report at all if there are no data for that date.

what is it I am missing here? 
any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Here you have to make a change in the query for data-driven subscription

```
DECLARE @Date AS DATETIME = '2018-01-01'

select 'aaa.bbb@xxx.com' EmailID
where (select count(*) from dbo.table 
WHERE [DateColumn] >= @Date) > 0
```

The query in where clause needs to be same as report dataset which you have used in binding report.

And this dataset value you have to use in ToEmail section of subscription.

Comment: this is not working.. i am still getting email with report attached but no records when there are no records. if there are records, then the data is in there in the report

Comment: If I specifically give date for which there is no record , then i am not getting any email. select 'aaa.bbb@xxx.com' EmailID where 1<=(select count(1) records from dbo.table where reportdate='20190215')   how ever, that date is dynamic and pulls the @report date from the report. 

I am giving report parameter while creating subscription but  with that, i get an email with attachment. 

If I specifically give the date, this is working. 

how do I dynamically pass the report variable in data set ?

Comment: You have to pass @Date as your report's date parameter too. So ideally your report parameter will be also come from dataset value.

Comment: In dataset for subscription you have to write same SQL query that you have used in report but instead of column you just need to get count of the records. So Date filter value you have to declare in subscription dataset query and that date filter you have to pass as parameter for SSRS report.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is something like this for your data driven subscription data set:

```
    DECLARE @Date AS DATETIME = '2018-01-01'


    if not exists(
    select top 1 *
    from dbo.table 
    WHERE [DateColumn] >= @Date) 

 raiserror ('Subscription need not run!',16,1)

 else
    select 'aaa.bbb@xxx.com' EmailID
    from dbo.table 
    WHERE [DateColumn] >= @Date
```

What this basically does is not return any data if there is nothing and fails your subscription.. no email is generated.. if the if condition passes, then everything else will run as you planned it.